# What does diamond have besides graphite?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, material-science, diamond

I know that diamonds are made of carbon atoms and graphite is made of carbon atoms too. The structure of both is also different. But do diamonds have any material or structure besides carbon to make it so strong?

Comment: FYI, different forms of the same pure chemical element are known as [allotropes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allotropy)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, they don't. Both [graphite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphite) and [diamond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond) are made out of pure carbon. The only difference between the two is their structure (i.e. formally speaking they are [allotropes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allotropy)):

- Graphite is made of hexagonal sheets of carbon atoms which are strongly bonded *within* the sheets but with looser bonds *between* one sheet and the next:

  [image]
- Diamond is made of a [diamond cubic lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_cubic) of carbon atoms where each atom has strong bonds to *four* neighbours in a three-dimensional tetrahedral arrangement:

  [image]

The reduced strength of graphite with respect to that of diamond comes from those looser [van der Waals bonds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_force) between the different sheets as opposed to the [covalent bonds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covalent_bond) that hold throughout the diamond lattice.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that the "strong" bonds between carbon atoms are covalent bonds and the sheets of carbon atoms in graphite are connected by the van der Waals force which is relatively weak.

Comment: @dylnan hmm... I thought it was a delocalized pi bond, similar to the aromatic ring in benzene?

Comment: @JohnDvorak [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphite#Structure) claims the bonding is from the van der Waals force, although they don't cite anything. That is an interesting question though and I'm not sure how the distinction would be measured. Maybe through STM? Maybe some argument could be made that since the delocalized electrons are conducting they can't form delocalized pi bonds. Not sure